# Issue with parsing the powershell variable into JSON array

Tags: json, powershell, variables

I'm using the following code to change a Pre-shared key for MEraki, however, at the moment I'm only able to do it statically.
I'd like to automate the code so that the PSK is an actual variable.

I've tried using the " or ' however in either scenario i'm unable to recall the variable into the array, and my end goal is to automate this script so that I can just run it and poof, off it goes.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11

function Get-RandomCharacters($length, $characters) {
$random = 1..$length | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum $characters.length }
$private:ofs=""
return [String]$characters[$random]
}

function Scramble-String([string]$inputString){     
$characterArray = $inputString.ToCharArray()   
$scrambledStringArray = $characterArray | Get-Random -Count $characterArray.Length     
$outputString = -join $scrambledStringArray
return $outputString 
}



$password = Get-RandomCharacters -length 5 -characters 'abcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters '1234567890'

$password = Scramble-String $password

$newDailyPassword = $password 

$newDailyPassword

#Meraki API KEY
$api_key = "API_KEY"
#Meraki Network URL
$network_id = "NETWORK_ID"
#Base API URL
$api = @{
"endpoint" = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0'
}
#API URL for SSID PSK Change XXX
$api_put = @{
    "endpoint" = 'https://nXXX.meraki.com/api/v0'
}

$header_org = @{
    "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key" = $api_key
    "Content-Type" = 'application/json'
}
# PSK = New password
$data = @{
    "psk" = $newDailyPassword   **#----> I'd like this to be the new daily password variable. Is there a way to do this?**
}
#Convert data to Json format
$jbody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data
#URL Network_ID and SSID number
$api.ssid = "/networks/$network_id/ssids/2"
#Combine base api_put URL and $api.ssid
$Merakiuri = $api_put.endpoint + $api.ssid
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $Merakiuri -Headers $header_org -Body $jbody -Verbose
```

EDIT1: I've managed to resolve this, by applying the concatination of the variable string, as I was parsing unexpected query via JSON (single string).

I've done the below.

```
$JsonJoiner = "'"
$passwordx = -join($JsonJoiner,$password, $JSonJoiner)  

$newDailyPassword = $passwordx
```

now, whenever I parse the
$newDailyPassword
the correct value is parsed, and i'm able to generate the PW.

Comment: [_When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed._](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#single-and-double-quoted-strings) Hence, `'$newDailyPassword'` returns _literally_ string `$newDailyPassword`.

Comment: When I just recall the variable, i'm unable to submit the request and the remote server returns the 400 error. 
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: I suppose it's a totally unrelated problem. Maybe the JSON you produce is not what the API expects after all.

Comment: I've actually managed to get around it by modifying the string produced by the variable and concatenating it. 

   $JsonJoiner = "'"
   $passwordx = -join($JsonJoiner,$password, $JSonJoiner)  

   $newDailyPassword = $passwordx

Thanks a lot for your help @marsze

Comment: Now you basically just surrounded the value with single quotes. A much simpler version: `"'$newDailyPassword'"`. However, this will AGAIN be quoted in double quotes when converted to JSON. But hey, if the API works that way ...